# A host in the mininet of a server sends packet to another host in the mininet of another server?

Tags: mininet, sdn

Is it possible?

I want to simulate more than 5000 hosts, which is impossible in one server due to the limitation of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to attach a physical interface on a server to connect to a Mininet virtual switch. Please refer to the script https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/hwintf.py. So if there are multiple mininet servers, we can have one physical interface on each server connected to the virtual switch running on that server. Thus we can connect the virtual switches running on different servers using the physical interfaces. This would also require configuration of flow entries to forward host traffic from one Mininet server to a host on other Mininet server. This is one possible option to connect virtual hosts on different Mininet servers.

Comment: Awesome!!  Thank you!